# About grass algorithm differenece between v.to.rast.value and v.to.rast.attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

When i use the `v.to.raster.value` algorithm in QGIS to convert vector polygon shapefile to raster, the algorithm runs but at later stage, during completion, it shows an error message that the output layer could not be loaded. Why is this happening?

I am using qgis v 2.8.2 32 bit in windows 8.1 64 bit os.

And my another question is what is the difference between two algorithms of grass `v.to.rast.value` and `v.to.rast.attribute`?

Can they be used selectively or they have some specific purposes?

Comment: As an answer to the second question; you can specify *fixed*  pixels value when using `v.to.rast.value`. And you can specify a column(field/attribute) that includes (likely different) values as pixels value by using `v.to.rast.attribute`.

Comment: Simply read the documentation  [Grass GIS:v.to.rast](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.to.rast.html)